# Add Field Errors with a Custom Entity Validator

Tags: java, validation

Working in java, I have some custom validators for my class: I can't just validate each field independently, as I have some conditions like "if 'A' then B cannot be null".

In this situation, I would like for the validator to be able to assign this as a FieldError to field B. Is there an easy way of doing this? My validators mostly look like this:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = TicketingLinkTextValidator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidateTicketingLinkText {
    String message() default
            "Ticketing link text must be entered in all languages if ticketing is enabled";
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}

public static class TicketingLinkTextValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidateTicketingLinkText,
        TicketingInformation> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidateTicketingLinkText constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(TicketingInformation ticketingInformation, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (!ticketingInformation.ticketsAvailable) {
            return true;
        }
        for (Language language : ticketingInformation.getText().keySet()) {
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(ticketingInformation.getText().get(language).getTicketingLinkText())) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```